# Normalize vectors in gensim model

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word-embedding

I have a pre-trained word embedding with vectors of different norms, and I want to normalize all vectors in the model. I am doing it with a for loop that iterates each word and normalizes its vector, but the model us huge and takes too much time. Does `gensim` include any way to do this faster? I cannot find it.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 7):

Gensim instances of `KeyedVectors` (the common interface of sets of word-vectors) contain a method `init_sims()`, which internally calculates unit-length normalized vectors using a native vector operation for speed.

When certain operations that are usually conducted on unit-normalized vectors are attempted for the 1st time, this `init_sims()` will be automatically called, and the model will cache the normalized vectors in a model property (`vectors_norm`) – roughly doubling the RAM consumption.

Once it's been called, you can access normed vectors using the `.word_vec()` method:

```
normed_wv = kv_model.word_vec(word, use_norm=True)
```

If you're sure you won't need the raw, un-normed vectors, you can also call `init_sim()` yourself with its optional `replace` parameter. Then, the normed vectors will clobber the raw vectors in-place – saving the extra RAM. For example:

```
kv_model.init_sims(replace=True)
```

Note that while things like finding the nearest-neighbors of a word, as in the common `most_similar()` operation, traditionally use unit-normalized vectors, there are sometimes downstream applications where the raw vectors are useful. (Also, in a full `Word2Vec` model, if you're going to do additional incremental training, that should happen on raw vectors, not normalized vectors.)

Comment: For the `KeyedVectors` model with loaded pretrained weights, it returns normalized values, but it doesn't normalize for `FastText`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. When this answer was written, in 2018, it accurately described how to ensure you could access normalized vectors in all relevant Gensim models, including `FastText`. In later versions of Gensim (including the time of this coment, late 2023), no separate `init_sims()` method or `.vectors-norm` variable are needed: you can just use `fasttext_model.wv.get_vector(word,norm=True)`, as with all the word2vec-family models, and per the docs & examples: https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/fasttext.html#gensim.models.fasttext.FastTextKeyedVectors.get_vector